# ¿Como obtener datos de una consulta join cuando la variable llega en el request Laravel?

Tags: laravel, join, querybuilder

Hola a todos de ante mano, gracias por sus respuestas, el tema es el siguiente:

Estoy obteniendo los empleados de mi base de datos con algunos Joins aplicando ciertos filtros que también son llegados del request el tema está en que de estos empleados debo hacer otro filtro los cuales cumplan con una condición para ser específico en mi request llega un dato con nombre "cat_periodicity_type_id" esta variable si es 11 debe aplicar un filtro a mis empleados donde solo obtenga aquellos empleados que tienen una incapacidad, la tabla que guarda las incapacidades de los empleados se llama employee_incidents y el campo que contiene el registro en esta tabla tiene como nombre "cat_employee_inability_type".
Esto me esta llegando en el request:

```
array:4 [
  "cat_contract_type_id" => []
  "start_date" => "2022/09/01"
  "end_date" => "2022/09/15"
  "cat_periodicity_type_id" => 4
]
```

Esta es la consulta que estoy generando:

```
 $employees = Employee::join('employments', function ($join) use ($end) {
                $join->on('employees.id', '=', 'employments.employee_id')
                ->where('employments.is_active', '=', true)
                ->where('employments.position_id', '!=', null)
                ->where('employments.date', '<', $end);
            })
                ->join('cat_movements', function ($join) {
                    $join->on('employments.cat_movement_id', '=', 'cat_movements.id')
                    ->where('cat_movements.is_active_payroll', '=', true);
                })
                ->join('positions', function ($join) use ($ids) {
                    $join->on('employments.position_id', '=', 'positions.id')
                        ->whereIn('positions.cat_contract_type_id', $ids);
                })
                ->join('employee_incidents', function ($join) use ($request){
                        $join->on('employees.id', '=', 'employee_incidents.employee_id')
                            ->where('employee_incidents.cat_employee_inability_type_id', '=!', null);
                })
                ->select(['employees.id', 'employees.name', 'employees.lastname', 'employees.second_lastname', 'employees.rfc', 'employees.code'])
                ->with('preventives.fiscal_exercise', 'preventives.fortnight')
                ->orderBy('employees.rfc')
                ->get();
```

Estaba intentando de esta manera en el join de la tabla pero no tengo éxito:

```
  ->join('employee_incidents', function ($join) use ($request){
                    if($request->cat_periodicity_type_id == 11) {
                        dd('if');
                        $join->on('employees.id', '=', 'employee_incidents.employee_id')
                            ->where('employee_incidents.cat_employee_inability_type_id', '=!', null);
                    }
                })
```

Temporalmente, aplique un if para solucionar el problema y poder avanzar les dejo el código (Se que no es la mejor solución):

```
  $employees = Employee::join('employments', function ($join) use ($end) {
                $join->on('employees.id', '=', 'employments.employee_id')
                ->where('employments.is_active', '=', true)
                ->where('employments.position_id', '!=', null)
                ->where('employments.date', '<', $end);
            })
                ->join('cat_movements', function ($join) {
                    $join->on('employments.cat_movement_id', '=', 'cat_movements.id')
                    ->where('cat_movements.is_active_payroll', '=', true);
                })
                ->join('positions', function ($join) use ($ids) {
                    $join->on('employments.position_id', '=', 'positions.id')
                        ->whereIn('positions.cat_contract_type_id', $ids);
                })
                ->select(['employees.id', 'employees.name', 'employees.lastname', 'employees.second_lastname', 'employees.rfc', 'employees.code'])
                ->with('preventives.fiscal_exercise', 'preventives.fortnight')
                ->orderBy('employees.rfc')
                ->get();

                if($request->cat_periodicity_type_id == 11) {
                    $employees = Employee::without('account')->join('employments', function ($join) use ($end) {
                        $join->on('employees.id', '=', 'employments.employee_id')
                        ->where('employments.is_active', '=', true)
                        ->where('employments.position_id', '!=', null)
                        ->where('employments.date', '<', $end);
                    })
                    ->join('cat_movements', function ($join) {
                        $join->on('employments.cat_movement_id', '=', 'cat_movements.id')
                            ->where('cat_movements.is_active_payroll', '=', true);
                    })
                    ->join('positions', function ($join) use ($ids) {
                        $join->on('employments.position_id', '=', 'positions.id')
                            ->whereIn('positions.cat_contract_type_id', $ids);
                    })
                    ->join('employee_incidents', function ($join) {
                        $join->on('employees.id', '=', 'employee_incidents.employee_id')
                            ->orderBy('employee_incidents.created_at')
                            ->whereNull('employee_incidents.deleted_at');
                    })
                    ->join('employee_incident_dates as eid', function ($join) use ($start, $end) {
                        $join->on('employee_incidents.id', '=', 'eid.employee_incident_id')
                            ->whereDate('eid.date', '>=', $start)
                            ->whereDate('eid.date', '<=', $end)
                            ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');
                    })
                        ->select([
                            'employees.id',
                            'employees.name',
                            'employees.lastname',
                            'employees.second_lastname',
                            'employees.rfc',
                            'employees.code',
                        ])
                        ->with('preventives.fiscal_exercise', 'preventives.fortnight')
                        ->groupBy('employees.rfc', 'employees.id')
                        ->distinct()
                        ->get();
                }
```

Estoy repitiendo la consulta a diferencia de que si cat_periodicity_type_id es igual a 11 añado un join a employee_incidents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Antes de ejecutar ->get(); puedes cortar la sentencia y añadir if por medio como lo que quieres hacer.
La variable $employees hasta que no llamas a la función get() es una clase contructura de la query que quieres hacer. Por ese motivo puedes concatenarle cualquier cosa en función de condicionales.

Te pongo un ejemplo que creo que es lo que estás buscando.

```
$employees = Employee::join('employments', function ($join) use ($end) {
        $join->on('employees.id', '=', 'employments.employee_id')
            ->where('employments.is_active', '=', true)
            ->where('employments.position_id', '!=', null)
            ->where('employments.date', '<', $end);
        })
        ->join('cat_movements', function ($join) {
            $join->on('employments.cat_movement_id', '=', 'cat_movements.id')
                ->where('cat_movements.is_active_payroll', '=', true);
        })
        ->join('positions', function ($join) use ($ids) {
            $join->on('employments.position_id', '=', 'positions.id')
                ->whereIn('positions.cat_contract_type_id', $ids);
        });
        if($request->cat_periodicity_type_id == 11){
            $employees->without('account')
                ->join('employee_incidents', function ($join) {
                    $join->on('employees.id', '=', 'employee_incidents.employee_id')
                        ->orderBy('employee_incidents.created_at')
                        ->whereNull('employee_incidents.deleted_at');
                })
                ->join('employee_incident_dates as eid', function ($join) use ($start, $end) {
                    $join->on('employee_incidents.id', '=', 'eid.employee_incident_id')
                        ->whereDate('eid.date', '>=', $start)
                        ->whereDate('eid.date', '<=', $end)
                        ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc');
                });
        }
        $employees->select([
            'employees.id',
            'employees.name',
            'employees.lastname',
            'employees.second_lastname',
            'employees.rfc',
            'employees.code',
        ])
        ->with('preventives.fiscal_exercise', 'preventives.fortnight')
        ->orderBy('employees.rfc')
        ->get();
```